# Edit MS Word .docx file in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word

Unzipping docx file (renamed to *.zip) I'v got several xml files.

Is there any way to add some sort of data (text) to this xml files using vba?

I need to place there a "hidden text" and when it need's, retrieve it.

**Update 1**

For example: in excel I have hidden sheets which store data received from server, it's Jsaon text ("hidden text"). I need something similar in Word, but not in active document. I know I can use DocVariable for this, but maybe there is another way.

**Update 2**

Question resolved, I decided to use DocVariable. Thanks for help.

Comment: Given your requirements, .docx may not be the right format for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you go to such lengths? Why can't the following work for you?

[image]

Comment: You can hide an entire page in Word too ... similar to hidden sheets in Excel ... unless there is something else you are trying to do here